# How do I invoke the search dialog using onSearchRequested()

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement the search dialog and I am unable to display the search from an Activity.

I have my main activity defined in my manifest file, this activity shows the user a list of options they have to choose from. One of the options is a Search option.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My Search activity is defined in my manifest file like so.

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity"  
              android:launchMode="singleTop"  
              android:label="@string/app_name">  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>  
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"  
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>  
</activity>
```

Now my problem is when I call the onSearchRequested() from my MenuListActivity nothing happens.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {  
          String strText = items[position];  

          if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_browse))) {  
              startActivity(new Intent(MenuListActivity.this, WSMobileActivity.class));  
          } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_search))) { 

            // If i call it like this it doesn't work, nothing happens  
              onSearchRequested();  

          } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_locator))) {
              startActivity(new Intent(MenuListActivity.this, StoreLocatorActivity.class));  
          }  
      }
```

Please help, how do I invoke the search request from my MenuActivity?

Comment: Could you accept some answer as the "Answer"?

Answer (score 26):

did you check your res/xml/searchable.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
  android:label="@string/search_label">
</searchable>
```

Search dialog doesn't show up when you have hard coded strings for hint and label. They have to be @string resources.

Also, there is no need to call or override the onSearchRequested() method in your calling activity unless you want to invoke search from one of your UI widgets like a Button or a ListItem.

Comment: Thank you _so_ much! Is it documented somewhere? I got stuck with this problem for quite a long time...

Comment: Glad to be able to help. I spent almost a week with this problem in my app. I discovered it the hard way.

Comment: Everything was set. I forgot to add that @string resources and went ahead with Hard coded values. That one line comment saved me hours of torture. Thanks :)

Comment: HOLY CRAP this needs to be documented somewhere!! This answer should definitely be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Apart from declaring the SearchActivity in the manifest file you need to include the meta-data info.

If you want to invoke the search dialog throughout the application then include

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchActivity" />
```

inside the application tag.

If you want to invoke the search dialog only in a particular activity then include

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchActivity" />
```

inside the activity tag.

for more details please refer 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html.

Comment: I have tried adding that into the Activity and Application as well. Nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing  tag in your activity tag in manifest. replace your activity declaration by following.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MenuListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" />

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done all that but still cannot see the search dialog on API 17. It works however after adding

android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"

in the fragment menu

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/search"/>
```